# Can not use inflater to inflate view into tabviews in ViewPagerindicator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

Im trying to change the code from the library project in ViewPagerindicator.

Here's the code snippet for the `addView()` method in `TabPageIndicator`

[image]

as you can see , I abandon the `TabView` class in the TabPageIndicator class, instead I inflate my own layout xml into the view(of course I did some modification in the onClick() method too). the xml below is the `R.layout.tabviewlayout`

[image]

However, no matter how I changed the parameters in the layout xml, the layout did not change at all(for example , adding borders as you can see in the background attr in the linearlayout,but it did not work)

[image]

Edit********************************************After adding parent

```
final View tabView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabviewlayout,mTabLayout,false);
```

[image]

the padding change, but the attributes for width height and border do not work at all still...

Answer (score 1):

> When inflating a layout, avoid passing null as the parent view, since
>   otherwise any layout params on the root of the inflated layout will be
>   ignored.

Instead of null, pass your mTabLayout in `.inlfate()` like `inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabviewlayout, mTabLayout);`

Comment: hi Markus, i tried add the parent, but it did not work, the UI change a little but just the padding between tabs. The border and width height attributes still not work at all. I edit my post for the updated UI.